# Слова "мусорка" и "мусорница"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика

Вопрос о словах "мусорка" и "мусорница": существуют ли вообще такие слова и есть ли различия между ними?

Answer (score 3):

Слова ***мусорка*** и ***мусорница/мусорник*** встречаются в текстах и приведены в орфографическом словаре, но в толковом словаре их пока нет.

В речи же они активно используются: ***мусорка*** ― это явно разговорный вариант, ***мусорница*** ближе к нейтральной речи. Конечно, это разговорные сокращения, правильно  ― мусорное ведро, мусорный контейнер. Правильно, но неудобно, поэтому  и говорят: выбросить в мусорку, отнести на мусорку.

Значение слов можно установить по морфемному составу и употреблению в речи.

1) **Мусорница/мусорник** ― суффикс НИК/НИЦ обозначает предмет, предназначенный для мусора.

**Мусорница** ―  корзина, урна, мусорник ―  контейнер, место, где стоят контейнеры, машина для перевозки мусора.

2) **Мусорка** образована по образцу кладовая ― кладовка, поэтому это скорее место для мусора. В то же время это может быть корзина или урна.

Примечание. Такой способ образования слов называется универбацией (мусорная корзина ― мусорка). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

3) **Мусоросборник** ― общее название.

4) **УРНА**, [лат. urna] 4. Сосуд или ящик для мусора, окурков, устанавливаемый на улицах, в общественных помещениях и т.п. Мусорная у. У. для бумаг.

**Примеры:**

Он был такой же достопримечательностью улицы, как и **мусорка** ― три огромных контейнера...[Маша Трауб. Замочная скважина (2012)]

Голова ― **мусорница** памяти, и кое-кто умеет делать из нее конфетку, складывая из своих историй сказки «Тысяча и одной ночи». [Дарья Симонова. Шанкр (2002)]

В этом заброшенном дворе лежал остов «жигулей», за ним был **мусорник.**..

На нормальной дороге Олег догнал бы этот **мусорник** в два счёта...